# How can I easily convert a numpy tuple to tuple tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have numpy tuple (with len 4, 5, 6, or more). How can I convert a numpy tuple to a Tensorflow tuple with input like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[20, 20], [40, 40]], dtype=np.int32)
b = np.array([[20, 20, 20], [40, 40, 40], [60, 60, 60]], dtype=np.int32)
c = np.array([[20, 20], [40, 40]], dtype=np.int32)
d = np.array([[20, 20, 20], [40, 40, 40], [60, 60, 60]], dtype=np.int32)
e = (a, b, c, d) # e is numpy tensor i want convert to tensor
tf_shapes = ((None, 2), (None, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3))
tf_types = (tf.int64, tf.float32, tf.int64, tf.float32)
```

I must write a generator to convert this to a Tensorflow tuple.

```
def data_generator():
    for i in range(16):
        yield a, b, c, d
dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, tf_types, tf_shapes).batch(batch_size=4, drop_remainder=True)
for sample in dataset:
     res = model(sample, training=False)
```

How can I get a sample directly without not using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it appears that you just want to have `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` converted to tensorflow tensors without having to use the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` function.
In that case, you can simply use `tf.convert_to_tensor`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, np.int32)
b_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(b, np.int32)
c_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(c, np.int32)
d_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(d, np.int32)

# use the tensors however you want
```

Additionaly, if you want to have a tensor that is similar to `e` in your code, then do:

```
e_tensor = tf.stack(e, axis=0)
# e_tensor[0] == a_tensor, e_tensor[1] == b_tensor, ...
```

Comment: a, b, c, d is not the same shape, i changed shape of a,b,c,d in the question.